# Acess denied for user (mysql and flask)

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am trying to connect to MySQL database in Flask as follows:

```
mysql = MySQL()
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'password'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'myDB'
mysql.init_app(app)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'myusername'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")
```

I tried reinstalling XAMPP but to no avail.
I have 2 issues:

1. Why am I getting the error for 'myusername' instead of 'root'?
2. How can I solve this issue?

SOLUTION:
I needed to grant the correct privilege to the specific user@localhost in MySQL.

Comment: have you given permission

Comment: What do you mean by permission? Permission to the root user to access myDB by using GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON myDB.* TO 'root'@'localhost';. If so, yes.

Answer (score 0):

By default in XAMPP root user doesn't have password, you can create a new one doing the following steps:

1. Click Admin next to MySQL on the XAMPP Control Panel to bring up the phpMyAdmin.
2. Choose the mysql database on the left.
3. Then, choose the SQL tab on the top and run the following statement:
   `SET Password=PASSWORD('password')`;

But, instead I highly recommend to create a new user:

```
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
CREATE DATABASE myDB;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON myDB.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost';
```

Comment: I already added a password to root using the SET Password=PASSWORD('password'); SQL statement. I also tried to create a new user with name 'myusername@localhost' as in the error above but in vain.

Comment: can you run `pip freeze`, also what version of XAMPP do you have?

Comment: XAMPP version 8.0.1. I did not get this information from pip freeze. The result of pip freeze is:click==7.1.2
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-MySQL==1.5.2
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.3
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
pkg-resources==0.0.0
PyMySQL==1.0.2
Werkzeug==1.0.1